# How can I properly change the domain of someones email address?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, email

I apologize if I'm not clear enough in my question.  Anyways I'm on a Windows Server 2003 domain. On that domain we have several other Organizational Units within that domain.  I'm still learning about AD but I believe the hierarchy is Domain then Directories. Well anyways let's say that one Directory is Test1 and the other is Test2. I'm in test1 so my email address looks like jason@test1.com. The other user is in the directory Test2 but her email address is user@test1.com. How can I properly change the domain of her email address to be test2? Other users in her are have the test2 domain.

If anyone needs any clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want user2 to be able to accept email @test2.com, all you have to do is add it in the AD email addresses frame.

If you want email to be sent as @test2.com, add it in the email address frame, then highlight it and click "Primary Address".  The @test2.com email address should go bold, indicating it is the primary address for that account.

Of course this all assumes you have a exchange cluster which understands which can handle users from both OUs in @test2.com, which depending on the complexity of your organization, may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain consists of an Exchange server then email addresses are based on your Recipient Policies. Do you have an Exchange server in your domain? If not, then what you're describing isn't an email address it's a UPN (user principal name) and it is set at the time of domain creation. Additional UPN's can be created and changed manually on a user by user basis. The directories you're describing are called Organizational Units (OU for short) and have no bearing on email addresses or UPN's.

How are you creating the test1.com and test2.com addresses?